# Issue when attempting to Add data entered by user

Tags: java

See code attached. The main intent here is to create a program(Java) that Adds, Divides, etcetera etcetera. So far I've only gotten as far as the addition block. for some reason when I attempt to add two user inputs together it concatenates them instead, when they are clearly entered separately as they are meant to be entered, according to my code. I have attached the code as well as several images to help you all understand what im trying to achieve. Any and all constructive criticism is welcome, I'm open to any suggestions...

PS: Using IntelliJ as Primary IDE.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNl8O.png) [Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnCu.png) [Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbe7.png) [Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Lxs.png) [Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwwIN.png) [Run Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVkmP.png)

PS: Images marked "run" are when code is running.

Thanks, hope you can help!

Comment: Well, you should add the code to your actual question instead of in an image. It makes it much easier to future readers to read, test and try out your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user input is a string. String represents text and when you add two strings together they will be concatenated. What you want is to add two numbers.
You can make an int(which represents a number) from the string by using the ParseInt() method:

```
int firstNumber =Integer.parseInt(useInput1);
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(useInput2);
```

When you have two ints you can add them together:

```
int total = firstNumber + secondNumber;
```

I advise you to read a bit about basic/primitive data types in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Marco, I will make sure to read up on my documentation, appreciate the suggestion, I had forgotten about ParseInt for a second there.